# Gson Serializing the Integer object

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm generating JSON using the Gson library. I'm attempting to generate JSON like:

```
{"Plaintext":{"type":"List","value":["1","2","3","4"]},"SINGLE_FUNCTION":{"value":"1"},"IN_FLOW":{"value":10}}
```

However, the JSON that is appearing is..

```
{"Plaintext":{"type":"List","value":["1","2","3","4"]},"SINGLE_FUNCTION":{"value":"1"},"IN_FLOW":{"value":{"value":10}}}
```

The problem, I found is that when my objects are being created, an `Integer` object is being stored. This is because of the type of the mapping is `Object`, which means the `int` type that I'm storing is automatically wrapped to type `Integer` and Gson is rendering the only non-null value, `value` inside the `Integer` class.

My question is, is there a way of having Gson render an `Integer` object as if it were a primitive type `int`?

**Edit**

So, The whole `JSON` is a `Map`. This Map is defined as:

```
private Map<String, ParameterWrapper> parameterMap;
```

The class `ParameterWrapper` looks like this:

```
public class ParameterWrapper<T> {

    private String type;

    private T value;

    public ParameterWrapper(String type, T value) {
        this.type = type;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

I suspect that because I'm not specifying a type `T` for `ParameterWrapper`, it's defaulting to `Object`, which is why Gson is outputting it as an `Object` and not an `int`, despite it being an instance of `Integer`.

Comment: primitive int isn't null-able, therefore where you have nulls, they'll be wrapped to Integer. Tried defaulting your int to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sample code (with [lombok](http://projectlombok.org/) `@Data` and guava [`Lists`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Lists.html)):

```
package so28235867;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import lombok.Data;

import java.util.List;

public class Foo {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Root root = Root.of(Plaintext.of("List", Lists.newArrayList("1", "2", "3", "4")), new Value<String>("1"), new Value<Integer>(10));
        System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(root));
    }

    @Data(staticConstructor = "of")
    // TODO: tweak JSON serialisation to respect naming convention
    static class Root {
        private final Plaintext Plaintext;
        private final Value<String> SINGLE_FUNCTION;
        private final Value<Integer> IN_FLOW;
    }

    @Data(staticConstructor = "of")
    static class Plaintext {
        private final String type;
        private final List<String> value;
    }

    @Data
    static class Value<T> {
        private final T value;
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
{"Plaintext":{"type":"List","value":["1","2","3","4"]},"SINGLE_FUNCTION":{"value":"1"},"IN_FLOW":{"value":10}}
```

And that looks like what you want. So you probably have an error in the definition of your object hierarchy.

Comment: Do you think that the problem might be with the fact that the reference type of `value` is of type `Object`, despite the fact that it is an instance of `Integer`?

Comment: I don't think so, but without seeing your classes definition it's hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: Added to the OP now. Hopefully that should be what you need.

Comment: Your are still not showing how you generate your JSON (and I don't see/guess how you use your map and wrapper). Please post a complete - with explicit dependency list if you have some - minimal sample (like mine), you can omit getters/setters if they are "standard", also note that `Integer` is serialized as a number in my posted sample without any setup or tweak, so..

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, is there a way of having Gson render an Integer object as if it were a primitive type int?

You can manually add the `IN_FLOW` (or any primitive) value as Integer primitive value.

```
jsonObject.add("IN_FLOW",new JsonPrimitive(obj.getInFlow()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this,

```
public T getValue() {
    return value;
}
```

to,

```
public T getValue() {
    if( value instanceOf Integer ) {
        return value.intValue();
    }
    return value;
}
```